# Firebug collapsing the whole tree

Tags: html, firefox, firebug, inspector

I have this problem with Firebug: when I open element via "Inspect in Firebug", every 5 seconds (approximately) the whole  tree is being collapsed, with  tag highlighted in yellow. How can I disable that feature? I usually use Chrome, but need Firebug for this project b/c of FirePHP, and it just drives me insane) There's no ajax or other network activity at the moments it collapses. Any help?

Update: This only happens in Wordpress admin/new page edit page - it refreshes some parts, apparently, and Firebug updates the inspector tree. If I turn on logging of mutation events, I can see this in console:
http://prntscr.com/3uataj
I can not change the way WP works, but is there a way to change Firebug behavior? How can I make it NOT collapse  on every change?

Comment: I'm noticing the same thing, for what it's worth - it looks like WP is periodically changing something on the root html element, judging by what's being highlighted in the HTML view. you're right, it's crazy, it makes it impossible to use firebug with the WP admin control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the highlighting of changed elements, there's an option in the [HTML panel options menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu) called *Highlight Changes*, which you need to uncheck.

You can also avoid tree expansions by unchecking the option *Expand Changes*.

[image: Highlight Changes and Expand Changes option in Firebug's HTML panel]

Though in some cases the HTML tree may still collapse. This is when a subtree is completely reparsed as it is done by assigning something to the `innerHTML` property of an element.

It may also be possible that there's a bug in Firebug, which is causing this in some cases. If you have a simple test case for this, you should post it to [issue 7469](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7469), so it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply! I've actually tried all the HTML menu checks/unchecks before posting here and it didn't help, but big thanks for explanation and bug link)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the HTML is modified within a `window.setInterval()` function. Check please.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't change html tree logic of Firebug with options or some simple methods.